# In a linear regression minimization problem, why does replacing the expectation by the empirical distributions lead to OLS?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference

The linear regression problem can be written in general by first considering random variables $X \in \mathbb{R}^p$ and $Y \in \mathbb{R}$. Then, the linear regression problem can be described as looking for:

$$
\arg\min_{\beta \in \mathbb{R}^p} \mathbb{E}\left[(Y-X\beta)^2\right]
$$

which has a closed form solution given by:

$$
\widehat{\beta} = \mathbb{E}[X^TX]^{-1}\mathbb{E}[X^TY]
$$

I read in a talk that if we replace the expectation $\mathbb{E}$ with respect to the distribution of $(X,Y)$, by the empirical distributions $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\delta_{Y_i}$ and $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\delta_{X_i}$, corresponding to our dataset, then we retrieve the Ordinary Least Squares regression problem.

Can someone tell me why this is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The empirical MSE is 
$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n( y_i - \widehat{\mathbb{E}y_i}  )^n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n( y_i - \hat{y}_i  )^2,
$$
such that $\hat{y}_i = \hat{\beta}_0 + \sum_{j=1}^p\hat{\beta}_j x_j$. As such, the problem is finding the $\hat{\beta}$s that minimize the empirical MSE. Now, note that you can multiple the target function by $n$, it is monotone transformation, thus does not change the solution. Hence, you get the following problem 
$$
\arg \min_{\beta \in \mathbb{R}^{p+1}} \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-\beta_0 - \sum_{j=1}^p\beta_j x_j)^2,
$$ 
which is exactly the OLS problem.

Comment: It seems that the talk I went to talked about replacing the expectations in $\widehat{\beta} = \mathbb{E}[X^TX]^{-1}\mathbb{E}[X^TY]$ with $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\delta_{Y_i}$. Am I able to do this?

Comment: Also, do you mean to have the terms of the sum in the first equation above to the power of $2$ instead of $n$?

Comment: 1. Yes, you are right. I've corrected. 2. What is $\delta_{Y_i}$?

Comment: It is the dirac delta point mass function with probability $1$ at $Y_i$ and $0$ everywhere else. Thanks!